# Questions on a modularity-based partitioning using networkx

Tags: networkx, modularity

given an edge list as seen in the code below:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities
from networkx.algorithms.cuts import conductance

# Create a networkx graph object
my_graph = nx.Graph() 

# Add edges to to the graph object
# Each tuple represents an edge between two nodes
my_graph.add_edges_from([
                        (1,2), 
                        (1,3), 
                        (3,4), 
                        (1,5), 
                        (3,5),
                        (4,2),
                        (2,3),
                        (3,0)])

# Draw the resulting graph
nx.draw(my_graph, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

# Modularity
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(my_graph))
```

We obtain as a cut:

```
[frozenset({0, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset({1, 5})]
```

If we look at its corrensponding graph:

[image]

why are here node 1 and 5 removed or considered as a good split, and not node 0 removed from the rest of the graph instead?

Thank you in advance for any hints
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the name `greedy_modularity_communities` and from the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities) the algorithm will always return a approximation of an optimal partition.

For the partition you proposed, you can simply check the values:

```py
from networkx.algorithms.community.quality import modularity

print(modularity(my_graph, [frozenset({0, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset({1, 5})]))
# 0.0546875
print(modularity(my_graph, [frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), frozenset({0})]))
# -0.0078125
```